# Raspberry pi robot wheels not moving

Tags: dc-motor, bridge

I need some help with a Raspberry Pi robot I am attempting to put together.

I'm using an L298N h-bridge to manage both DC motor wheels. I have a simple python script on the Pi which should simply drive the bot forwards and backwards. However, the wheels don't move. Instead I just hear a low pitched whine.

I am powering the Pi and the h-bridge from 5V usb ports off a power bank. For the h-bridge, I connected each motor to A and B, to ground and to 5V.

To eliminate the potential that both DC motors are damaged, I put the positive and negative leads from a 9V battery to the solder points of each DC motor and both respond ... spinning fast in one direction and in the reverse when I switch the polarity of the battery leads.

So, I got my multimeter and tested the current at the h-bridge power connection and I get just under 5V as pictured below:
[image]

When I tested the connections for each motor, I got 0.23V - which I'm guessing is the [problem](https://youtu.be/81ZmFZW27aw).

**Can anyone please advice on how I can solve this problem and get my robot moving?**

Comment: `tested the current` `get just under 5V` .... you did not test the current, you measured the voltage .... unit of measurement for current is amp (A)

Comment: your power supply is unable to provide enough current to drive the motors

Comment: your troubleshooting process is flawed .... if the motor does not turn when connected to a bridge that is powered by 5 V supply, then use the 5 V supply directly to test the motor ... do not use a 9 V battery to test the motor

Comment: You could probably get this result if your h-bridge is wired into the circuit wrongly, among other things.

Comment: @jsotola: I take your point. I tested the motors using a 5V connection and the wheels responded

Comment: You might loose those 0.23V at the jumperwires. What current is the motor intended to sink?